# Import RSS as posts with redirect?

Tags: redirect, rss, excerpt

I'm looking for a way to import RSS items from an **external blog** as posts *with a redirect* on them.

The purpose is to have another blog's posts show up in my front page excerpts but actually deliver the user to the source blog upon clicking.

Does anyone know of a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called [FeedWordpress](http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/) that does just that.

It will appear as Syndication in your admin panel.

The Posts & Links configuration panel of Syndication will control where the post title links to.  The original source is an option.

Comment: didn't work with all server :(